# Partial Derivatives Approximation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, approximation

By definition we know the following:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \approx \frac {f(x+ \delta x,y)-f(x,y)}{\delta x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \approx \frac {f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)}{\delta x}
\end{equation}

Is the following approximation true?
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial ^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} \approx \frac {f(x+ \delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x+ \delta x,y)+f(x,y)}{\delta x \delta y}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes.

By the definition of partial derivative:

$
\cfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=\lim_{k \to 0} \left( \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0+k) - \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) \right)k^{-1}=\lim_{k \to 0} \lim_{h \to 0} \cfrac{f(x_0+h,y_0+k)-f(x_0,y_0+k) - f(x_0+h,y_0) + f(x_0,y_0)} {hk}
$

Comment: Interestingly, this approximation is the same in whichever order of derivatives, but the derivatives are not necessarily equal! To think about it: under which conditions are they equal?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP was told that the approximation is true which is even obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A useful formula

$$\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y} \approx  \frac{f(x+h,y+k) - f(x+h,y-k) - f(x-h,y+k) + f(x-h,y-k)}{4hk}$$

See more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Finite_difference_in_several_variables).